# The thread pool accepts new tasks even when at maximum capacity in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

When I am learning Thread Pool in C# yesterday, I tried to create an example that will create a Thread Pool that enables two thread to enter the Thread Pool(`MaxThreads`) while give it 4 assignment in total. Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPoolExample_0();
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
    public static void ThreadPoolExample_0()
    {

        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(2,2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Task), i);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Task(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task {0} is running on a thread from the thread pool.", state);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Task {0} exited.", state);
    }
```

However, it will output this dialog, which means that thread will enter the Thread Pool even it is full. Here is the dialog:

*Task 3 is running on a thread from the thread pool.


Task 0 is running on a thread from the thread pool.


Task 1 is running on a thread from the thread pool.


Task 2 is running on a thread from the thread pool.


Task 0 exited.


Task 3 exited.


Task 1 exited.


Task 2 exited.*

I wonder what's wrong with my code, or if my understanding of the C# thread pool is incorrect.

Comment: [You cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors on the computer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=net-7.0) Does your CPU have 4 cores?

Comment: @shingo thanks for answering my question! my CPU is `12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900H   2.90 GHz` I tried to set max threads to 50 and give 200 tasks and that works. I wonder if I should delete this question or waiting for you(or someone else) to write a whole answer, so that other people who are facing the same issue can find a quick solution

Comment: Related: [ThreadPool frustrations - Thread creation exceeding SetMaxThreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488966/threadpool-frustrations-thread-creation-exceeding-setmaxthreads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on ThreadPool:

> You cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors on the computer. To determine how many processors are present, retrieve the value of the Environment.ProcessorCount property.

You probably have more than 4 CPUs, so setting the number of threads to 2 is a noop.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the [number of processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount) on the computer. If you try to do it, the [`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads) returns `false`, and the initial settings are preserved. It's a good idea to call the `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads` after calling the `SetMaxThreads`, to verify visually that the `ThreadPool` has been configured according to your wishes. Just checking the return value of the `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` [is not 100% reliable](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/80072).