# Effect of lock keyword on a Parallel.ForEach loop

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

This is more a conceptual question. I was wondering if I used a `lock` inside of `Parallel.ForEach` loop if that would take away the benefits of parallelizing a `foreach` loop.

Here is some sample code where I have seen it done.

```
Parallel.ForEach<KeyValuePair<string, XElement>>(binReferences.KeyValuePairs, reference =>
{
    lock (fileLockObject)
    {
        if (fileLocks.ContainsKey(reference.Key) == false)
        {
            fileLocks.Add(reference.Key, new object());
        }
    }

    RecursiveBinUpdate(reference.Value, testPath, reference.Key, maxRecursionCount,
        ref recursionCount);

    lock (fileLocks[reference.Key])
    {
        reference.Value.Document.Save(reference.Key);
    }
});
```

Where `fileLockObject` and `fileLocks` are as follows.

```
private static object fileLockObject = new object();
private static Dictionary<string, object> fileLocks = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

Does this technique completely make the loop not parallel?
I would like to see your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3):

It means all of the work inside of the `lock` can't be done in parallel.  This greatly harms the performance here, yes.  Since the *entire* body is not all locked (and locked on the same object) there is still some parallelization here though.  Whether the parallelization that you do get adds enough benefit to surpass the overhead that comes with managing the threads and synchronizing around the locks is something you really just need to test yourself with your specific data.

That said, it looks like what you're doing (at least in the first locked block, which is the one I'd be more concerned with at every thread is locking on the same object) is locking access to a `Dictionary`.  You can instead use a `ConcurrentDictionary`, which is specifically designed to be utilized from multiple threads, and will minimize the amount of synchronization that needs to be done.

Answer (score 3):

> if I used a lock ... if that would take away the benefits of Paralleling a foreachloop.

Proportionally. When `RecursiveBinUpdate()` is a big chunk of work (and independent) then it will still pay off. The locking part could be a less than 1%, or 99%. Look up Amdahls law, that applies here.

But worse, your code is not thread-safe. From your 2 operations on `fileLocks`, only the first is actually *inside* a lock.

```
lock (fileLockObject)
{
    if (fileLocks.ContainsKey(reference.Key) == false)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

and

```
lock (fileLocks[reference.Key])   // this access to fileLocks[] is not protected
```

change the 2nd part to:

```
lock (fileLockObject)
{        
    reference.Value.Document.Save(reference.Key);
}
```

and the use of `ref recursionCount` as a parameter looks suspicious too. It might work with Interlocked.Increment though.

Comment: Your change to the second `lock` block is overly pessimistic.  The intent of the code was so that only operations on the same file are synchronized, so that saving two different files can be done at the same time.  Saving is a potentially very expensive operation, and so this is worth a bit of extra time/effort in managing the synchronization.  Yes, the OP's code has a bug in it, and it should be fixed, but it can be solved by simply accessing the dictionary's value in the global lock instead (or, as my answer suggests, using a `ConcurrentDictionary` to handle the lookup).

Comment: You're probably right that the saving can be pulled out of the lock, I didn't look thaat deeply. But there is a bug and as long as it's not fixed, performance ain't gonna matter.

Comment: @Servy the second lock would contradict your answer because you said that this would lock on the same object.

Comment: @diaz994 I fail to see what has contradicted my answer.  Henk is proposing *not* locking on different objects and instead choosing to only lock on a single object.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to locks, there's no difference in the way PLINQ/TPL threads have to wait to gain access. So, in your case, it only makes the loop not parallel in those areas that you're locking and any work outside those locks is still going to execute in parallel (i.e. all the work in `RecursiveBinUpdate`).

Bottom line, I see nothing substantially wrong with what you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

The "locked" portion of the loop will end up running serially.  If the `RecursiveBinUpdate` function is the bulk of the work, there may be some gain, but it would be better if you could figure out how to handle the lock generation in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the response Reed. What do you mean handle the lock generation in advance? Im not really following there.

Comment: @diaz994 In your case, the initial lock could be avoided by creating the keys before you parallelize.  The save could also be done after processing.

Comment: But wouldn't that cause to iterate through the references twice? That would cause some extra overhead that way. @Reed Copsey

Comment: @diaz994 iteration is typically quite fast - you might be able to use PLINQ to turn it into a 2 phase select (first builds the "locks", second does the processing), then do ForAll to save at the end...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing conceptually wrong with using the `lock` statement in a `Parallel.ForEach` loop. If done correctly, the effect of the `lock` on the overall performance of the parallel operation can be totally negligible. An uncontended `lock` is really cheap. It can be acquired and released in as little as 20 nanoseconds on a 2010-era computer, in other words in can be acquired and released 50,000,000 times per second ([citation](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking_Performance)). On the other hand if the `lock` is used incorrectly, it can completely serialize the `body` delegate, negating all the benefits of parallelization. Or even worse, as in the code snippet presented in your question, it can be applied incorrectly and allow concurrent access on [non-thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2#thread-safety) state (`fileLocks`), resulting in undefined behavior.

The general advice is: do the least amount of work while holding the `lock`, and release it at the earliest opportunity. Don't do work inside the `lock` that can be done outside the `lock`.

Regarding the specific problem that the code in the question is attempting to solve, which is to prevent parallel processing for `reference` objects having the same `Key`, locking on the `Key` might not be the optimal strategy. That's because it blocks [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) threads, and also because it may result in reduced degree of parallelism. Your code does not specify the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism), implying unlimited parallelism, which in practice means that the effective degree of parallelism will be determined by the `ThreadPool` availability, which is a bit chaotic¹. In case you change your mind and decide to specify the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, and you also desire to maintain a constant degree of parallelism during the whole operation, the simple use of the `lock` won't cut it. You want the parallelization devoted to doing actual work, not occupied by waits for a lock. You could look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71000722/dynamically-processing-a-concurrent-collection-in-parallel-by-group-but-serially/71026983#71026983) for a more sophisticated approach on this specific problem. That answer is about the asynchronous [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync), but adjusting it to the synchronous `Parallel.ForEach` should be straightforward.

¹ <sub>My [personal advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538452/what-does-maxdegreeofparallelism-do/75287075#75287075) is to specify always the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` when using the `Parallel` APIs.</sub>