# Using millions of Tasks leads to the error System.OutOfMemoryException (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task, out-of-memory, .net-6.0

I have 6 million small (average size about 15 bytes) files that I need to read and further process using the processor. I have previously implemented this using Task.Factory and it worked on asp.net core 2.1 without problems. It took about 20 hours.

I have now migrated the app to asp.net 6 and on the test server, my web application stops responding to any requests after starting these file operations. In the log I see the error `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

I suppose my way of implementation is far from ideal. I would like to know what ways of multi-threaded implementation of this work can you suggest?

Method `ImportSignatures` from controller:

```
[HttpPost("ImportSignatures")]
public JsonResult ImportSignatures()
{
    try
    {
        return Json(SignatureImportService.ImportSigningCerts());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogsHelper.WriteLog("api/Settings/ImportSignatures", e);
        return Json(new ImportSigningCertsResult(e.Message, SignatureImportService.WasCancelled));
    }
}
```

Method `ImportSigningCerts`:

```
public static ImportSigningCertsResult ImportSigningCerts()
{
    LogsHelper.WriteEventLog("Launching SignatureImportService");
    WasCancelled = false;
    IsWorking = true;
    ResultStr = "";
    totalSignatures = 0;
    processedSignatures = 0;

    var cancelMsg = "Certificate import was interrupted. \n";
    var endMsg = "Certificate import completed successfully. \n";
    var toDelete = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        var configuration = SignatureImportConfiguration.FromCfg();

        using (s_tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            List<string> signatures = Directory.EnumerateFiles(configuration.Path, "*.sig").ToList();
            totalSignatures = signatures.Count;

            Store mainStore = StoreMan.GetStore("Main");
            var importStats = new ImportStats();
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            int saveIndex = 1;
            const int proccessedForSave = 100000; // After what number of processed signatures to perform intermediate storage and deletion of signatures
            CancellationToken token = s_tokenSource.Token;

            int minWorkerThreads, minCompletionPortThreads, maxWorkerThreads, maxCompletionPortThreads;
            ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out minWorkerThreads, out minCompletionPortThreads);
            ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out maxWorkerThreads, out maxCompletionPortThreads);
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(minWorkerThreads * 2, maxCompletionPortThreads);

            signatures.ForEach(path =>
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    // Here reading of a current file and uploading the necessary certificates to the store from it
                    if (UploadSigningCerts(mainStore, path, importStats))
                    {
                        if (configuration.NeedCleaning)
                        {
                            lock (s_toDeleteListLockObj)
                                toDelete.Add(path);
                        }
                    }

                    // Here intermediate store's saving and deleting proccessed files
                    lock (s_intermediateSaveLockObj)
                    {
                        if (++processedSignatures > proccessedForSave * saveIndex)
                        {
                            LogsHelper.WriteEventLog("Intermediate saving of the certificate store...");

                            mainStore.WriteIfChanged();
                            StartRemovingSignatures(toDelete);
                            saveIndex++;
                        }
                    }
                }, token));
            });

            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                foreach (Exception e in ae.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    if (e is not TaskCanceledException)
                        LogsHelper.WriteLog("SignatureImportService/ImportSigningCerts", e);
                }
            }
            mainStore.WriteIfChanged();
            StartRemovingSignatures(toDelete);
            ResultStr = (WasCancelled ? cancelMsg : endMsg) + $"Certificates found: {importStats.all}. Was imported: {importStats.imported}." + (importStats.parsingFailed > 0 ? $" Unrecognized files: {importStats.parsingFailed}" : "");
        }

        LogsHelper.WriteEventLog(ResultStr);
        return s_tokenSource == null ? new ImportSigningCertsResult(ResultStr) : new ImportSigningCertsResult(ResultStr, WasCancelled);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        IsWorking = false;
    }
}
```

Method `UploadSigningCerts`:

```
private static bool UploadSigningCerts(Store store, string path, ImportStats importStats)
{
    bool toBeDeleted = true;
    CryptoClient client = CryptoServiceContext.DefaultInstance.CryptoClient;

    try
    {
        List<CertInfo> certs = client.GetSignCmsInfo(File.ReadAllBytes(path)).Certs.ToList();

        Interlocked.Add(ref importStats.all, certs.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < certs.Count; i++)
        {
            lock (s_importLockObj)
            {
                // Validating each certificate from a file, making an import decision, importing to the store...
            }
        }
        return toBeDeleted;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogsHelper.WriteLog("SignatureImportService/UploadSigningCerts", e);
        LogsHelper.WriteEventLog($"Error importing certificate from signature: {Path.GetFileName(path)};");
        Interlocked.Increment(ref importStats.errors);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Method `StartRemovingSignatures`:

```
private static void StartRemovingSignatures(List<string> toDelete)
{
    if (toDelete.Count > 0)
    {
        List<string> tempToDelete;
        lock (s_toDeleteListLockObj)
        {
            tempToDelete = new List<string>(toDelete);
            toDelete.Clear();
        }

        LogsHelper.WriteEventLog("Deleting successfully processed signature files...");

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            tempToDelete.ForEach(path =>
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LogsHelper.WriteLog("ImportResult/DeleteSignatures", e);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Error's text:

```
20.08.2023 11:58:01 api/Settings/ImportSignatures
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.EnsureContingentPropertiesInitializedUnsafe()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.AssignCancellationToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Task antecedent, TaskContinuation continuation)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TaskConstructorCore(Delegate action, Object state, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, InternalTaskOptions internalOptions, TaskScheduler scheduler)
   at Store.Services.SignatureImportService.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<ImportSigningCerts>b__0(String path)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at Store.Services.SignatureImportService.ImportSigningCerts()
   at Store.Controllers.SettingsController.ImportSignatures()
```

Comment: To start try to remove the _Directory.EnumerateFile(...).ToList()_ because this loads all files in memory. Instead of ToList leave the EnumerateFiles alone and use its IEnumerable<string> return to feed the foreach loop

Comment: Mullti-Threading will make issue worse.  I would add a USING block in the foreach so after each file is processed the object will be disposed and may solve issue.

Comment: Also the line that takes the _Count_ makes the materialization of the IEnumerable

Comment: The exception call stack clearly indicates that "The common language runtime cannot allocate enough contiguous memory to successfully perform an operation", so read the Remarks section and follow the tips, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=net-7.0#remarks

Comment: This exception usually occurs when the memory usage of the application exceeds the available memory due to a large number of concurrently executing tasks. While multithreading can improve processing speed, too many concurrent threads can lead to memory exhaustion. Instead of starting tasks for all files at once, consider limiting the number of concurrent tasks. You can use SemaphoreSlim to control the maximum number of active tasks.

Comment: @Steve I need to get the number of files for the progress bar. Is there another way to get it without the materialization of the IEnumerable?

Comment: @jdweng If I use the `using` to work with the `Task`, I won't be able to wait for the completion of all tasks at the end, or do I not understand something?

Comment: @YurongDai I limit threads using `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`. Do you think it doesn't help? Or is it not about the one-time execution of threads, but about their one-time creation?

Comment: You have a lock so only one gets executed at a time.

Comment: In the overall schema, the progress bar is probably not so much critical as the rest of your work. Replace it with a counter that increments at each file processed just to show to your users the program is not stuck but still working. They need to wait.

Comment: Have you considered using the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Thanks, I have already solved the problem

Comment: @Steve - `.Count` ***never*** materializes the enumerable. And `.Count()` only does so in limited situations. It wouldn't here if `.Count` we replaced with `.Count()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the error `System.OutOfMemoryException` and I want to share my actions. Key points:

- I refactored the code, methods `ImportSignatures` (from controller), `ImportSigningCerts` and `UploadSigningCerts` are now asynchronous;
- Instead of using `Task` with array accumulation, I use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 3` limitation.

Now my code looks like this:
Method `ImportSignatures` from controller:

```
[HttpPost("ImportSignatures")]
public async Task<JsonResult> ImportSignatures()
{
    try
    {
        ImportSigningCertsResult res = await SignatureImportService.ImportSigningCerts();
        return Json(res);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogsHelper.WriteLog("api/Settings/ImportSignatures", e);
        return Json(new ImportSigningCertsResult(e.Message, SignatureImportService.WasCancelled));
    }
}
```

Method `ImportSigningCerts`:

```
public static async Task<ImportSigningCertsResult> ImportSigningCerts()
{
    LogsHelper.WriteEventLog("Launching SignatureImportService");

    WasCancelled = false;
    IsWorking = true;
    ResultStr = "";
    signaturesCount = 0;
    processedSignatures = 0;

    var cancelMsg = "Certificate import was interrupted. \n";
    var endMsg = "Certificate import completed successfully. \n";

    try
    {
        var configuration = SignatureImportConfiguration.FromCfg();

        using (s_tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            string[] signatures = Directory.GetFiles(configuration.Path, "*.sig");
            signaturesCount = signatures.Length;

            Store mainStore = StoreMan.GetStore("Main");
            ImportStats importStats = new();

            const int partSize = 100000; // After what number of processed signatures to perform intermediate storage and deletion of signatures

            var options = new ParallelOptions()
            {
                CancellationToken = s_tokenSource.Token,
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 3
            };

            try
            {   // Dividing the total array into parts containing partSize elements in order to perform intermediate saving and deleting of processed files
                foreach (string[] signsChunk in signatures.Chunk(partSize))
                {
                    List<string> toDelete = new();
                    try
                    {
                        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(signsChunk, options, async (signPath, _) =>
                        {
                            bool canBeRemoved = await UploadSigningCerts(mainStore, signPath, importStats);
                            if (canBeRemoved && configuration.NeedCleaning)
                            {
                                lock (s_toDeleteListLockObj)
                                    toDelete.Add(signPath);
                            }
                            Interlocked.Increment(ref processedSignatures);
                        });
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        LogsHelper.WriteEventLog("Intermediate saving of the certificate store...");

                        mainStore.WriteIfChanged();
                        StartRemovingSignatures(toDelete);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogsHelper.WriteLog("DeloWebSignatureImportService/ImportSigningCerts:Parallel.ForEachAsync", e);
            }

            ResultStr = (WasCancelled ? cancelMsg : endMsg) + $"Certificates found: {importStats.all}. Was imported: {importStats.imported}." + (importStats.parsingFailed > 0 ? $" Unrecognized files: {importStats.parsingFailed}" : "");
        }

        LogsHelper.WriteEventLog(ResultStr);
        return s_tokenSource == null ? new ImportSigningCertsResult(ResultStr) : new ImportSigningCertsResult(ResultStr, WasCancelled);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsWorking = false;
    }
}
```

Method `UploadSigningCerts`:

```
private static async Task<bool> UploadSigningCerts(Store store, string path, ImportStats importStats)
{
    CryptoClient client = CryptoServiceContext.DefaultInstance.CryptoClient;

    bool toBeDeleted = true;
    byte[] signatureData = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);
    CertInfo[] certs = Array.Empty<CertInfo>();

    try
    {
        certs = client.GetSignCmsInfo(signatureData).Certs;

        Interlocked.Add(ref importStats.all, certs.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < certs.Length; i++)
        {
            lock (s_importLockObj)
            {
                // Validating each certificate from a signature, making an import decision, importing to the store...
            }
        }
        return toBeDeleted;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogsHelper.WriteLog("SignatureImportService/UploadSigningCerts", e);
        LogsHelper.WriteEventLog($"Error importing certificate from signature: {Path.GetFileName(path)};");
        Interlocked.Increment(ref importStats.errors);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Everything else remained unchanged. Thanks to everyone who wrote comments, you guided me on the right path))

Comment: This looks like a verbose, inefficient, and potentially buggy attempt to reinvent the functionality that is already available in the [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) class.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, do you think so? I will study your suggestion, maybe you are right... I'll text you later

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I implemented your approach using the `Parallel.ForEach`. So the code really looks neater, nothing superfluous. However, for some reason, when testing Parallel.ForEach with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set at 2x of the cores' number, it showed itself much slower - 11h of work versus 7h using `SemaphoreSlim` and `Task`s. I have set the limit now to 3x - it has become more or less similar to the "best" result - 8h. I think I'll leave it that way. In any case, thank you for your advice))

Comment: Try calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism, Environment.ProcessorCount);` before starting the parallel loop. The `Parallel.ForEach` uses `ThreadPool` threads, so you will need plenty of them if your are doing blocking I/O. Alternatively you could switch to asynchronous I/O and the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API, so that you can have high concurrency using only a few threads. You could also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538452/what-does-maxdegreeofparallelism-do/75287075#75287075) of mine.

Comment: Btw I see that you are using the `Parallel.ForEach` inside a `for` loop. This is not the correct usage for this API. Also seeing the line `Interlocked.Increment(ref processedSignatures);` I have the impression that you are still trying to do manually work that the `Parallel.ForEach` is designed to do for you. Your code should be much simpler than it currently is. For batching the `signatures` you could use the [`Chunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk) LINQ operator.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I don't need to use `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` because in the process of executing the program, I observe that the maximum number of threads is involved, equal to the limit I set. If I don't set a limit, then I have an average of about 60 threads on a 4-core machine... Threads are involved to the maximum

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, why is using the `Parallel.ForEach` inside a `for` loop not correct? I found this method better than blocking threads inside `Parallel.ForEach` to track the number of processed files to save storage. According to the tests without the `for` loop, the program was executed for about 15 hours, with a `for` - of 7 hours...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I didn't understand why you don't like the line `Interlocked.Increment(ref processedSignatures);`. What other options are there for performing increment inside threads without blocking?

Comment: When a `Parallel.ForEach` operation is about to complete, the effective degree of parallelism is reduced. That's because the workload is rarely so perfectly balanced, to keep all workers running till the last millisecond. Placing the `Parallel.ForEach` in a loop means that you are going to pay this "penalty of imbalance" multiple times instead of just once. As for the `Interlocked.Increment`, it's not that I don't like it. You might have legitimate reasons to use it. I haven't studied your code deeply. I am just expressing my feeling, based on what looks superficially as red-flag of misuse.

Comment: If you are using the `Interlocked.Increment(ref processedSignatures);` for reporting progress, it's OK. If you are using it for controlling the execution flow, it's a red flag of doing something that you shouldn't.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, `processedSignatures` used for  reporting progress. Okay, I totally understand you. Thanks a lot :-)