# How to prevent to create more threads than the available number of hardware threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have the following method below that used to initialize and start log files processing by creating a different task for each file. In the Task Manager I can see this function is creating about one hundred threads this way.

```cs
public async Task LogProcessing(DescriptorList files, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var file in files)
        tasks.Add(new Task(() =>
        {
            ParsingFile(file, ct);
        }));

    foreach (var task in tasks) { task.Start(); }
   
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);       
}
```

**How can I prevent creating more threads than the available number of hardware threads?**
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't u use threadpool?  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Also from the performance point of view is better because of the reused threads. (https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/thread-pooling/)

Comment: @DA: Does task created this way will not run on the on _ThreadPool_?

Comment: No... because task.Start(); is scheduling it for execution to the current TaskScheduler and this is queuing tasks onto threads and not threadpool. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start?view=netcore-3.1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @Da From your own link "The default scheduler for the Task Parallel Library and PLINQ uses the .NET thread pool"

Comment: @JonasH - Was an example for performance. Nothing else.

Comment: Why not just use a Parallel.For/foreach-loop? That should try to partition the work to limit the number of threads used, and also allow for a explicit limit for the number of threads.

Comment: Also note that you need to be careful when trying to parallelize work that involves reading from files. Spinning disks *hate* random IO, and even SSDs prefer sequential reads.

Comment: @JonasH: I'll check the `Parallel.ForEach` methods. In my cases the files is transferred thru the network as a stream (from the SQL Server): the file operations are almost not involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .NET 6.0 or later you could use [`Parallel.ForEachAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) to do this:

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    files,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, CancellationToken = ct },
    async (file, cancellation) =>
    {
        await Task.Run(() => ParsingFile(file, cancellation), cancellation);
    });
```

Note the use of `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount` to limit the number of concurrent threads to the (logical) processor count. This is actually usually the default, so you may not need to set this at all, but some folks might like to do so for clarity.

According to the documentation "Generally, you do not need to modify this setting" but you should look at [this answer from Theodor Zoulias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538452/what-does-maxdegreeofparallelism-do/75287075#75287075) before using the default. (I generally don't use the default myself).

I recommend reading [the documentation on `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) and deciding for yourself whether to specify it or not.

As per TheodorZoulias's comments below, you can write this more simply as:

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    files,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, CancellationToken = cancelSource.Token },
    (file, cancellation) =>
    {
        ParsingFile(file, cancellation);
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    });
```

However, if `ParsingFile()` was itself `async` you would of course use the first version.

Comment: Thanks! It's what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually for the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API, as well as the anticipated in .NET 8 [`Parallel.ForAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.forasync) API, the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount` is the default. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism#remarks).

Comment: Also the `await Task.Run(() =>` is redundant. The default `TaskScheduler` of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` method is the `ThreadPool` anyway. You can just call the `ParsingFile`, and then return `ValueTask.CompletedTask` (no `async`).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I'm using the **.NET 7** and the default `TaskScheduler` is used. So can I just simplify the code above?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @Jackdaw the default [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.taskscheduler) is the [`TaskScheduler.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default). If you print it on the Console, you'll see that the actual type is `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, which is an internal .NET type. Both versions in Matthew's answer have identical behavior. The second version (`return ValueTask.CompletedTask;`) is slightly more efficient.

Comment: @Jackdaw btw although the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount` is the default, configuring it explicitly is better than relying on the default. I would not advise to remove this configuration from Matthew's answer.

Comment: *"Generally, you do not need to modify this setting"* -- FYI I [strongly disagree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538452/what-does-maxdegreeofparallelism-do/75287075#75287075 "What does MaxDegreeOfParallelism do?") with this advise given in the docs!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Note that the "conscientious and informed decision" signal is diluted when configuring the setting becomes widely recommended.

Comment: @BenVoigt the official documentation recommends keeping the default, or in other words to not configure this setting. It's unlikely that Microsoft will change this recommendation any time soon. And when people need technical advice they are looking first and foremost at the official documentation, not at my posts in StackOverflow. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I'm thinking less about people reading your posts and more about "if it's that good an idea, it will appear in some Fortune 500 companies' coding standards, and then you'll have people doing it merely because it is in the coding standard without putting in any thought"  Whether the person who wrote the coding standard say your post or independently thought about it and reached the same conclusion.

Comment: @BenVoigt ah, now I understand what you mean. That if the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount` becomes widely recommended, people will copy-paste it without thinking about it. Probably you are right. Although in my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538452/what-does-maxdegreeofparallelism-do/75287075#75287075) I had in mind the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1`, which is the default, and also the one that I recommend against. Writing this strange thing down (`-1`) certainly communicates prior thinking and intention IMHO!